# Why does a query return a result if the field is numeric and the WHERE clause is a string?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am running a query on a db table which is returning one record when I expect it to return no records.

```
SELECT yeargroupID FROM tbl_yeargroup WHERE yeargroup='S' AND schoolID=2.
```

The yeargroup field is a tinyint field. Thefore the WHERE clause is looking the letter 'S' in the numeric field, so should not find anything. Yet it returns the record with the yeargroup = 0, and yeargroupID=17 (the bottom record in the table)

[image]

I'm confused as to why it is returning this record and how to avoid it.

Thanks

Comment: You can avoid it by not comparing strings with numbers. Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: Because it converts the string to int, yielding 0.

Comment: Good to know - thanks. I've found a work around where I can test if the value is numeric of not, and adjust the query.

Comment: Because MySQL prefers doing "something" rather than throwing an error (even if that "something" doesn't make sense). There are three sensible ways to deal with such a condition: throw an error because comparing numbers and strings makes no sense (this is what Postgres does). Convert the number to a string or convert the string to a number but fail if the string isn't a number (which is what e.g. Oracle does). But MySQL chose the fourth one: if something can't be converted to a number it simply assumes it to be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic, as you have pointed out, is comparing a number and a string:

```
WHERE yeargroup = 'S'
```

Handling such situations is an important part of most SQL compilers, and it is well [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html).  The solution is to implicitly convert values to "conforming" types.  This is sad.  My preference would be for the compiler to generate an error and force the user to use correct types.  I find that implicit conversion creates more problems than it solves.

In any case, the rules in this case are pretty simple.  The string is converted to an integer.  But, how is a string with no digits converted?  Well, the rule *in MySQL* is that the leading digits are converted to a number.  And if there are none, the value is `0`.  So, this turns into:

```
where yeargroup = 0
```

You can see the results more clearly if you run:

```
select 'S', 'S' + 0
```

Note that most databases would return an error in this case (a type conversion error).  But even those would accept the string if it looked like a number, so this would be allowed:

```
where yeargroup = '5'
```

What is the proper solution?  *Never* mix types.  Do not construct queries by munging constant values.  Instead, queries from an application should always be using parameters.

Comment: Great - thanks for taking the time to explain Gordon.